# Get input from user in class

Tags: python, class, init

```
class Person:
  def __init__(self, name, age):
    self.name = name
    self.age = age

p1 = Person("John", 36)

print(p1.name)
print(p1.age)
```

How do I ask a user to input name and age?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do it in init. If in Python 2.7, use raw_input

```
class Person:
    def __init__(self):
        self.name = input('Name: ')
        self.age = int(input('Age: ')

p1 = Person()

print(p1.name)
print(p1.age)
```

Or if you want to keep it outside

```
class Person:
    def __init__(self,name,age):
        self.name = name
        self.age = age


name = input('Name: ')
age = int(input('Age: '))

p1 = Person(name,age)

print(p1.name)
print(p1.age)
```

Comment: Beat me by 10 seconds! haha

Comment: Doing it in `__init__` is a bad idea; prompting for keyboard input shouldn't be the constructor's job. Also, it prevents you from initializing a `Person` from anything *but* keyboard input, or using anything but those particular prompts.

Comment: Totally true. +1 ;) But it depends on the need! If you want to initiate the class with users values,for example. <Edited.>

Answer (score 0):

[This](https://www.pythonforbeginners.com/basics/getting-user-input-from-the-keyboard) would help but the simple answer is:

```
class Person:
  def __init__(self, name, age):
    self.name = name
    self.age = age

p1 = Person((raw_input("Enter Name"), int(raw_input("Enter Age"))))

print(p1.name)
print(p1.age)
```

Comment: @Alexander_Alvaer `raw_input` only works in Python 2

Comment: I see, using 3.7

Answer (score 0):

[The `input` function](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_func_input.asp) is made to get input from the user. You can create a new `Person` based on user input like this:

```
p1 = Person(input("What is your name?"), int(input("What is your age?")))
```

Here's a way that guards against non-integer user input when entering their age:

```
name = input("What is your name?")
try:
    age = int(input("What is your age?"))
except:
    print("Invalid input.")
    exit()
p1 = Person(name, age)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `input()` for Python 3:

```
name = input('Enter your name:')
age = input('Enter your age: ')
```

and `raw_input()` for Python 2:

```
name = raw_input('Enter your name:')
age = raw_input('Enter your age: ')
```

Do note that you would need to cast your `age` to `int` when reading inputs from the user as you'll get a string value.

```
age = int(age)
```

But be aware that if the user gives an invalid `int` its going to throw an error